# A Python script to plot data and save to PDF

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdf

I have a very simple Python script. All it does is open two data files from a given directory, read the data, make a series of plots and save as PDF. It works, but it is very slow. It takes almost 20 seconds for data files that have 50-100 lines and <30 variables.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

with open('file1.out') as f:
    var1 = f.readline().split()
with open('file2.out') as f:
    var2 = f.readline().split()

df1 = np.loadtxt('file1.out', skiprows=1, unpack=True)
df2 = np.loadtxt('file2.out', skiprows=1, unpack=True)

nc1 = df1.shape[0]
nc2 = df2.shape[0]
  
with PdfPages('file_output.pdf') as pdf:

    ## file1.out
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11,7))
    j = 1
    for i in range(1,nc1):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(3,2,j)
        ax.plot(df1[0], df1[i], linestyle='-', color='black')
        ax.set(title=var1[i], xlabel='seconds', ylabel='')
        if j == 6:
            pdf.savefig(fig)
            fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11,7))
            j = 1
        else:
            j = j + 1
    pdf.savefig(fig)

    ## file2.out
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11,7))
    j = 1
    for i in range(1,nc2):
    ... # and it continues like the block of code above
```

My questions are:

- Do I need all those imports and are they slowing down the execution?
- Is there a better way to read the data files then opening them twice (once to get the file header and once to get data)?
- Am I using the matplotlib commands correctly/efficiently (I am not very familiar with matplotlib, and this is basically my first attempt to use it)?

Please keep in mind that ideally this script should have as few dependencies as possible, because it is meant to be used on different systems by different users.

The data files have the following format:

```
              t             X1             X2             X3             X4             X5             X6             X7             X8            X11            X12            X13            X14            X15            X16
  6.000000E+001  4.309764E-007  2.059219E-004  9.055840E-007  2.257223E-003  1.148868E-002  7.605114E-002  4.517820E-004  3.228596E-008  2.678874E-006  7.095441E-006  1.581115E-007  1.010346E-006  1.617892E-006  9.706194E-007  
  1.200000E+002  4.309764E-007  2.059219E-004  9.055840E-007  2.257223E-003  1.148868E-002  7.605114E-002  4.517820E-004  3.228596E-008  2.678874E-006  7.095441E-006  1.581115E-007  1.010346E-006  1.617892E-006  9.706194E-007  
  1.800000E+002  3.936234E-007  2.027775E-004  8.644279E-007  2.180931E-003  1.131226E-002  7.476778E-002  4.353550E-004  3.037527E-008  2.534515E-006  6.778434E-006  1.470889E-007  9.488175E-007  1.531702E-006  9.189112E-007
```

Comment: Can you provide a small example input file for which the code works exactly as intended to demonstrate it's capabilities? This tends to make writing reviews easier, leading to higher quality reviews.

Comment: is it correct to have the two `with` statements which define the same `var1`, together at the top? Shouldn't it (maybe?) be `var2` in the second `with` statement and in the omitted second code block? (obviously it would be nicer to have that code block only once!)

Comment: @Max yes you are right, I have corrected the original question, thanks.

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @pacmaninbw I think it's counter-productive that you undid this correction of just one single typo, and not at all in the spirit of the instructions you linked to. There are zillions of examples on SE where experienced users edited the question to clarify, improve readability, and avoid ambiguities. In the case at hand, fixing this typo has no impact on the single answer given and on the contrary, avoids irrelevant answers motivated by that typo instead of focussing on the relevant part of the question.

Comment: @Max On Code Review we take answer invalidation very seriously. Besides, the code that is posted is supposed to work and be provided in its context, not as MCVE. We are different in that regard than other sites, like Stack Overflow. If the code has been modified and not tested before posting, the problem is with the code and not with the rollback of the edit. However, if no invalidation has happened and the answer still applies fully, the edit can stay. It looks like the answer already assumed this to be a typo.

Comment: @Mast OK... actually, the code will most probably work, it will just use the column titles of the second input files for both (which is correct if they are identical...). I think the edit should have stayed because it would avoid irrelevant discussions, but well, I won't insist further.

Comment: @Max The edit was rolled back around the same time when I posted my comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## coding style

Your code is almost pep-8 compliant. There are a few spaces missing after comma's, but all in all this is not too bad. I myself use [black](https://github.com/ambv/black) to take care of this formatting for me.

some of the variables names can be clearer. What does `nc1` mean for example

## magic numbers

The number 3, 2 and 6 are the number of rows and columns on the grid. Better would be to make them real variables, and replace 6 with `rows * columns`. If you ever decide you want 4 columns, you don't have to chase down all those magic numbers

## looping

You are looping over the indexes of `var` and `df`. Better here would be to use `zip` to iterate over both tables together. If you want to group them per 6, you can use the `grouper` [itertools recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes). and `enumerate` to get the index of the different subplots.

```
rows, columns = 3, 2

for group in grouper(zip(var1[1:], df1[1:]), rows * columns):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11, 7))
    for i, (label, row) in enumerate(filter(None, group)):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(rows, columns, i + 1)
        ax.plot(df1[0], row, linestyle="-", color="black")
        ax.set(title=label, xlabel="seconds", ylabel="")
```

The `filter(None,...)` is to eliminate the items that get the `fillvalue` in the `grouper`

Is a lot clearer than the juggling with `nc1` and `j`

## functions

This would be a lot easier to test an handle if you would separate the different parts of the script into functions

- reading the file
- making 1 page plot
- appending the different pages

This will also allow each of those parts to be tested separately

## reading the file

Instead of loading the file twice  and using `numpy`, using `pandas`, which supports data with names and indices will simplify this part a lot

```
df = pd.read_csv(<filename>, sep="\s+", index_col=0)
```

this is a labelled DataFrame, so no more need to use `var1`  for the column names

## making the individual plot:

### group the columns per 6

```
def column_grouper(df, n):
    for i in range(0, df.shape[1], n):
        yield df.iloc[:, i:i+n]
```

this simple helper generator can group the data per 6 columns

### make the plot

```
def generate_plots(df, rows=3, columns=2):
    for group in column_grouper(df, rows * columns):
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11, 7))
        for i, (label, column) in enumerate(group.items()):
            ax = fig.add_subplot(rows, columns,i + 1)
            ax.plot(column, linestyle='-', color='black')
            ax.set(title=label, xlabel='seconds', ylabel='')
        yield fig
```

## saving the pdf

Here a simple method that accepts an iterable of figures and a filename will do the trick

```
def save_plots(figures, output_file):
    with PdfPages(output_file) as pdf:
        for fig in figures:
            pdf.savefig(fig)
```

## pulling it together

```
def parse_file(input_file, output_file, rows=3, columns=2):
    df = pd.read_csv(input_file, sep="\s+", index_col=0)
    figures = generate_plots(df, rows, columns)
    save_plots(figures, output_file)
```

and then calling this behind a [`main` guard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/419185/1562285)

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_files = ['file1.out', 'file2.out']
    output_file = 'file_output.pdf'

    for input_file in input_files:
        parse_file(input_file, output_file)
```

If this still is too slow, at least now the different parts of the program are split, and you can start looking what part of the program is slowing everything down

Comment: Thanks, looks great. I am getting an error `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'items'` which I think is related to the output of `column_grouper()`, but I am not sure I understand exactly what that function does.

Comment: [`DataFrame.items`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.items.html). This should work. It worked for me at least. I didn't test the pdf creation, but the plot generation worked.

Comment: Ah, so it should be `for i, (label, column) in enumerate(group.iteritems()):` in the `generate_plots()` function.

Comment: I think both items and iteritems should work

Comment: thanks a lot, this has been really helpful. The script is part of a larger (open source) program. Are you happy for me to upload this code to github? With proper credits of course.

Comment: Sure, go ahead.

Comment: I have a doubt that this works. Your `parse_file` re-opens the `output_file` but `help(PdfPages.__init__)` says `The file is opened at once and any older file with the
        same name is overwritten.`.

Answer (score 0):

Maarten's answer contains lot of useful advice but I think his code won't work as expected because the `parse_file()` function which is called for each of the input files re-opens the `output_file`, but `help(PdfPages.__init__)` says ([cf. "Parameters" in the doc](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/backend_pdf_api.html#matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages))

> *The file is opened at once and any older file with the same name is overwritten.*

(Anyway, I don't think one can just append something to a PDF file, so unless PdfPages() would read in the whole PDF and re-write it entirely after appending content, it is not possible to reopen an existing file to simply append stuff.)

So I think we must open the output file only once and then loop over the input files, thus replacing the main loop and the two functions `parse_file` and `save_plot` by one single function, e.g., as follows:

```
def plotToPDF(output_file, *input_files, rows=3, columns=2):
    import pandas as pd
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
    with PdfPages(output_file) as pdf:
        for file in input_files: 
            df = pd.read_csv(input_file, sep="\s+", index_col=0)      
            for fig in generate_plots(df, rows, columns):
                pdf.savefig(fig)
```

which you would simply call as `plotToPDF('file_output.pdf', 'file1.out', 'file2.out')`.

This uses Maarten's function `generate_plots()` (requiring `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and  his other function `column_grouper()`) which can remain exactly as given in his answer.